# Xpath for <a></a> tag

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

**Let say this is my html code**

```
<a class="" data-tracking-id="0_Motorola" 
   href="/motorola?otracker=nmenu_sub_electronics_0_Motorola">

Motorola
</a>
```

I used C# code to find the **href** value like this

```
 var tags = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='top-menu unit']
                        //ul//li//div[@id='submenu_electronics']//a");
        if (tags != null)
        {
            foreach (var t in tags)
            {
                var name = t.InnerText.Trim();
                var url =t.Attributes["href"].Value;

            }
         }
```

I am getting **url='/motorola'** but I need  **url=/motorola?otracker=nmenu_sub_electronics_0_Motorola**
its not appending text after ?,&.. Please clarify where I went wrong.

Comment: What is your `t` object? Show how you create it.

Comment: what happened there? Was that edit by @st4hoo correct?

Comment: @st4hoo you can find now what is object. Please say where I went wrong

Comment: @user3487646: What is the type of htmlDoc? Are you using HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: @st4hoo Yes I am using Htmlagility pack

Comment: @user3487646: Your code works fine, `url` is equal to '/motorola?otracker=nmenu_sub_electronics_0_Motorola'. Make sure that you do not postprocess `url` somehow.

Comment: Maybe your html has additional <a> tags? <div id="submenu_electronics><div><a href="motorola" /></div><a href="motorola?otracker=">Motorola</a></div>

Answer (score 1):

I have used HtmlAgilityPack in the past and I have previously used it like this :

```
var url = t.GetAttributeValue("href","");
```

You can try that and see if it works.